# Difference between Apple Pro M2, M2 and M1 using Stable Diffusion

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance, apple-silicon

I am benchmarking Stable Diffusion on MacBook Pro M2, MacBook Air M2 and MacBook Air M1.

My assumption is the [ml-stable-diffusion](https://github.com/apple/ml-stable-diffusion) project may only use CPU cores to convert a Stable Diffusion Model from PyTorch to Core ML.

I tested the conversion speed on macOS 14, when converting DreamShaper XL1.0, the speed is M1 > M2 > Pro M2... M1 is the fastest one.

Then I tried Realistic XL, the conversion speed is M1 > Pro M2 > M2.

M1 is still the winner.

I think that doesn't make sense due to Apple reporting the speed should be ordered from fastest to slowest as M2 Pro > M2 > M1.

Does anybody know how I can understand this and perhaps get better speeds from M2 and Pro chips?

(Updated 2023/10/24)
I test twice for the model "DreamShaper XL1.0" on these 3 devices, all are 16GB RAM. The test result is as the table. The Pro M2 is twice faster Than last time I test (last time is about 16XXX seconds).

So by the table, the conversion speed is M1 > Pro M2 > M2. The only different is when converting the unet.

[image: Converting time benchmark table]

Comment: This is very interesting. Are you able to generate a screen image from Activity monitor to graph the CPU and GPU history for each of the chips during a benchmark run? Perhaps the code is single threaded and somehow the M1 is better optimized, but you should have more metrics to assist you from Instruments (in Xcode) and plain Activity Montitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found its Python version effects.
Python 3.9.6 on M2 Pro vs Python 3.11.5 on M1, M1 will run conversion faster than M2 Pro.

If they are on the same Python version, their speed will be M1 < M2 < M2 Pro.